# Does gerrithub.io have a support forum or public issue tracker?

Tags: gerrit, gerrithub.io

I have lots of questions about gerrithub.io itself and somehow it seems that they succeeded in hiding any information about a public issue tracker (not gerrit tracker itself, gerrithub one!) or a user forum or mainling list.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently they don't have support forum and public issue tracker specific for gerrithub.io. You can try the general Gerrit ones.

- [Gerrit Support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/repo-discuss)
- [Gerrit public issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/list)

Anyway, you could try do send your question to gerrithub.io team using the [contact form](http://gerritforge.com/contact.html).